# Is it possible to import all modules listed in child module?

Tags: python-3.x

Let's suppose I have a lot of stuff to load in my file, like so:

```
import finplot as fplt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import indicators
from indicators import bf_numpy
import mxnet
import mxnet as mx
from mxnet.gluon import nn, rnn
from mxnet import np as np_
import time
from blocks_utils_v2 import *
```

Is it possible to put all this stuff into another module so I could load them in one line of code?

Answer (score -1):

Aapperently yes: `from child import *` imports all the modules imported in child. Now I will have 1 line of code instead of 11 lines in my file.